# Details of Matzah Oven

Tags: passover, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, matzah

i've been looking for a valid oven to use to bake a soft laffa style Matzah. This is not easy as you can't make those things in a typical western oven, and to buy an oven for that purpose is quite costly or takes up a lot of space. Well i stumbled upon the following oven from the Nosach Teiman website but i can't figure out the Hebrew (i can only read Biblical Hebrew well). Can someone tell me what this advertisement says, whether this oven is electrical or gas lit, and if it has any details on its permissibility of matzah baking (i see the word matzah but don't know the context of its usage.

[image]

Comment: Is this off-topic because it's asking for a translation of Hebrew or on-topic because it's about a specific Judaism-related product?

Comment: @Daniel it might be, but this seemed like the place that might have the most knowledge about it

Comment: It says electric.

Comment: In case you're wondering what a "מכבזה" is: "Lay your flattened ball on a round cushion. Actually it wasn’t a cushion. It was a Machbazi, a specialist wicker instrument with a handle on the back and a padded cushion on the front, which when used is entirely covered in a separate piece of white cotton. But in the absence of a Machbazi you might use a cushion." http://balaganrecipes.info/yemenite-pita/

Comment: @Aaron You might want to chime-in on our discussion in chat starting [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26201177#26201177)

Comment: It says that it is an electric oven that can be used to bake matzos for Pesach and has two heating elements.

Comment: See also [a related question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206650/what-effects-will-a-220-to-110-transformer-have-on-an-electric-oven) on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  It was asked by the same asker.

Answer (score 5):

This is an electric oven

> For baking Yemmenite Pitas (*saluf*) and *Matzah* for *Pesah*. Including two electric heaters and a warranty for factory defects but not for the results of your baking.
>
> <sup>My approximate translation</sup>

Comment: לא לתוצאותיו isn't a joke that they don't guarantee you're a good baker?

Comment: i assume the price is 800 shekels, and will i need a power converter if using this in the US, does it say anything about wattage?

Comment: @DoubleAA Ah yeah I think you're right about that.

Comment: @Aaron Doesn't say anything about wattage. For something like that, I wouldn't use just a plain adapter. Even converters/transformers aren't a great idea for electrical appliances that heat up. For safety reasons, I wouldn't use this unless you are actually in Israel.

Comment: @Aaron not sure but I think Israel runs on 240 volts. That may preclude the ability to run this on 120 in America and still get kosher matzah.

Comment: @user6591 Why would it preclude it from making kosher matzah?

Comment: @Aaron it might not get hot enough on 120. Besides the fact running a 240 device on 120 can lead to it bursting into flames if it can't handle the current which is doubled when the voltage is halved. Just saying, check into it really well before proceeding.